# delete images from folder in php

Tags: php

I tried to add a delete images function in my website, but when I try, I was prompt a blank page as it doesn't echo anything and it doesn't remove any file from my folder..

Image.php

```
<form action="deleteImage.php" method="post">
    <input name="delete_file" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $one_image["FILE_NAME"]?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
    </form>
```

deleteImage.php

```
if (array_key_exists('delete_file', $_POST)) {
$path = "images";
$filename =  $_POST['delete_file'];
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        unlink($path . "/" . $filename);
        echo 'File ' . $filename . ' has been deleted';
    } else {
        echo 'Could not delete ' . $filename . ', file does not exist';
    }
}
```

Comment: You are checking `if (file_exists($filename))`, but trying to delete using `unlink($path . "/" . $filename);`? So you either need to add the `$path . "/" . ` to your `file_exists()` -> `if (file_exists($path . "/" . $filename))` **or** remove it from the `unlink()` -> `unlink($filename);`, depending on the file location

Comment: @Sean it's working, thanks!

Comment: Give me 30 seconds with this web page and I will wipe out all your images, and maybe your entire website. Filter your input.

Answer (score 1):

try to run the following code

```js
if (array_key_exists('delete_file', $_POST)) {
$path = "images";
$filename =  $path . "/" . $_POST['delete_file']; // build the full path here
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        unlink($filename);
        echo 'File ' . $filename . ' has been deleted';
    } else {
        echo 'Could not delete ' . $filename . ', file does not exist';
    }
}else{
    echo 'error';
}
```